# Display current stock quote on webpage

Tags: javascript, php

I want to display current stock price of particular company of BSE &  NSE, on my webpage (using php)... How to implement it? Please guide me about.

I have tried [this](http://www.financialcontent.com/support/documentation/json_quote_api.php) link...but it's not showing current market price for BSE & NSE. Is there any other way then please let me know...

```js
<script>

  function updateQuotes(data) {
   for (ticker in quote) {
    var symbol = quote[ticker];
 
    document.write('<div>Price of ' + ticker + ' : Close -  ' + symbol['Last'] + '</div>');
 document.write('<div>Price of ' + ticker + ' : Low -  ' + symbol['Low'] + '</div>');
 document.write('<div>Price of ' + ticker + ' : High -  ' + symbol['High'] + '</div>');
 document.write('<div>Price of ' + ticker + ' :Open - ' + symbol['Open'] + '</div>');
 
   }
  }
 </script>
 
 <script src="http://feeds.financialcontent.com/JSQuote?Ticker=GOOG"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please post the code you've tried so far

Comment: I have posted my code above..when I try for BSE/ NSE then it's not working, also unable to format it as per my requirement too...So Please help me about...

Answer (score 2):

The reason its not showing the market price for BSE and NSE is because you never ask for them in your call.

What you need to do is define them in your script src like this

```
<script src="http://feeds.financialcontent.com/JSQuote?Ticker=GOOG+BSE+NSE"></script>
```

This will return the correct data for updateQoutes to parse.

If you want this to be dynamic you could also do some string substitution with Jquery on that src attr but I'll leave that for you to work out :)

**EDIT: for just BSE and NSE**

```
<script src="http://feeds.financialcontent.com/JSQuote?Ticker=BSE+NSE"></script>
```